# $emit from child controller works, but $broadcast from parent scope doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I call `$scope.$broadcast` none of the events my children are listening to are getting triggered.  A simplified example is below:

### HTML

Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
    <b>Parent Event:</b> {{outer}}<br />
    <b>Child Event:</b> {{inner}}<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

### AngularJs

```
mc = angular.module('app', [
  'app.controllers',
]);

angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
        $scope.outer = 'not executed';
        $scope.$broadcast('EventFromParent');
        $scope.$on('EventFromChild', function () { 
          $scope.outer = 'executed';
        });        
    }])
    .controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.inner = 'not executed';
        $scope.$on('EventFromParent', function () { 
          $scope.inner = 'executed';
        });
        $scope.$emit('EventFromChild');
    }]);
```

### Output

I expect to see triggered for both Parent and Child, but I don't get triggered for Child.

```
EXPECTED                      ACTUAL
------                        ------
Parent Event: triggered       Parent Event: triggered
Child Event: triggered        Child Event: not triggered
```

### Theory

My guess here is that the child controller is not ready to receive events.  That I need to wait until the DOM is ready, but I don't see how to do that with Angular.  Feel free to tell me that this is just the wrong way to go about what I'm doing too.

## [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ukM8SzITpOvrvrMg4qYr?p=preview)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is `$scope.$broadcast` in parent controller is called before `$scope.$on` in child controller, so there is no listeners for this event at the time when the 'EventFromParent' is broadcasted to child scope.

You need to register event listeners before broadcasting or emitting an event. In your case, one way to achieve that is to use `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('EventFromParent');
});
```

(You will need to inject `$timeout` service first)

This way, you have effectively delayed the event broadcasting, and the event listener has got chance to register itself, so when the event happens, the listener will be called.

Comment: @DanielGimenez why would you be broadcasting events when the controller is instantiated?  Seems like that's the sort of thing that belongs in `module.run()`.

Comment: @c0bra, Maybe it should be in module.run()?  If you have a better idea, feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: @c0bra `module.run()` might or might not be the proper place, because in run block, all you have is `$rootScope` and broadcast on root scope might have side-effect. But in this simplified case, @DanielGimenez you can for sure try to put it in run block.

Comment: I still needed $timeout in run, so didn't seem the point of using it.  Seems like I'm missing something, but this works for now.

Comment: I just mean that this all seems theoretical and has no actual use case behind it. If you're wanting to make sure something is done and available in your controller then you could (if using ngRoute), put a resolve on the path that the controller serves, or inject a service that supplies a promise. An event handler that operates only once, on instantiation, doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @c0bra Indeed! This question is over simplified, it's hard to give a more practical advise.

Comment: 0I have a dashboard with n controllers that all contact an api when the user hits the page.  I don't want them running all at once.  The controllers know nothing of the other's state.  The parent knows nothing about the child controllers.  I have an object that is like a promise that is an argument to the event that allows the orderly processing, and is the only link they have with each other.  This context seemed too distracting to my core issue at the time, so I left it out.  Maybe I will post a new question, but I'm afraid it will be flagged as opinion based.

Comment: What about creating a service that my children could all register with?  They'd pass their init method and get queued up.  Replaces the parent controller entirely.

Comment: @YeLiu Is there a potential race condition here, or is the timeout callback guaranteed to fire after descendant controllers are initialized from the DOM?